CSS Transition Issue for JS Created Elements
I would like to implement some animation for the hp-bar as it changes. For context, this is a Chrome extension for a browser game to display team information.
I had a previous version that worked fine, but I refactored the code so I could arrange the team member cards alphabetically. The width/color of the hp-bar is behaving as expected.
I have tried calling setHp() both before/after the appendChild elements, switching the transition property into JS .hp-container, including it in the function itself, and changing CSS from .hp-bar to #cardOneHP, #cardTwoHp, ....
I suspect that this has something to do with how JS is creating the elements and that's interfering with a smooth transition, but I am not sure how to solve.


const hpBarGreen = "#39ff7b";
const hpBarYellow = "#f3b200";
const hpBarRed = "#fb3041";

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
      if (request.data) {
        const party = request.data;

        const members = [];

        function createMemberObject(partyMember, index) {
          if (!partyMember) return null;

          return {
            id: `member${index + 1}`,
            originalName: partyMember.name,
            sortName: partyMember.name.replace("G-Max ", "").replace("Mega ", ""),
            form: partyMember.form,
            level: partyMember.level,
            typeOne: partyMember.types[0],
            typeTwo: partyMember.types[1],
            teraType: partyMember.teraType,
            status: partyMember.status,
            currentHp: partyMember.currentHP,
            maxHp: partyMember.maxHP
          };
        }

        for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
          const memberObject = createMemberObject(party[i], i)
          if (memberObject) {
            members.push(memberObject);
          }
        };

        function displayMembers(members) {
          const popup = document.querySelector(".popup");
          popup.innerHTML = "";

        members.forEach(member => {
          const card = document.createElement('div');
          card.className = 'pokemon-card';
          card.id = member.id;

          card.innerHTML = `
            <div class="sprite">
                <img class="pokemon-sprite" id="${member.id}Sprite" src="./images/pokemon/${
                  member.form ? `${member.sortName}-${member.form}` : `${member.sortName}`
                }.png" alt="">
                <img id="${member.id}Form" src="" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="stats">
                <div class="line-one">
                    <div class="name" id="${member.id}Name">${member.sortName.toUpperCase()}</div>
                    <div class="level-container">
                        <p id="${member.id}LevelText">Lv.</p>
                        <p class="level-number" id="${member.id}Level">${member.level}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="line-two">
                  <div class="types">
                      <img id="${member.id}TypeOne" src="${
                        member.teraType ? `./images/tera-types/${member.teraType}.png` : `./images/types/${member.typeOne}.png`
                      }" alt="">
                      <img id="${member.id}TypeTwo" src="${
                        member.teraType ? "" : `./images/types/${member.typeTwo}.png`
                      }" alt="">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="line-three">
                    <img id="${member.id}Status" class="status" src="./images/status/${member.status}.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="line-four">
                    <div id="${member.id}HpBar" class="hp-container">
                        <div id="${member.id}ActiveHp" class="hp-bar"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          `;

          popup.appendChild(card);
      });
    }
      members.sort((a, b) => a.sortName.localeCompare(b.sortName));
      displayMembers(members);

      const hpPercentage = (members[0].currentHp / members[0].maxHp) * 100;
      const hpBar = card.querySelector(`#${members.id}ActiveHp`);

      console.log(members[0].currentHp, members[0].maxHp);

      function setHp(percentage, hp) {
        hp.style.width = (percentage) + "%";
        if (percentage <= 25) {
          hp.style.backgroundColor = hpBarRed;
        } else if (percentage <= 50) {
          hp.style.backgroundColor = hpBarYellow;
        } else {
          hp.style.backgroundColor = hpBarGreen;
        }
      };
      
      setHp(hpPercentage, hpBar);
    }
  }
);
@font-face {
  font-family: False-Positive;
  src: url(./fonts/falsepos.ttf);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-family: False-Positive;
  color: #333333;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.popup {
  width: 500px;
  height: 800px;
  background-color: #e5e4c5ff;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.pokemon-card {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ffffcc;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-items: center;
  border: #777777 solid 2px;
}
  
.sprite {
  min-width: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
  
.pokemon-sprite {
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  grid-row: 1 / span 3;
  max-width: 85%;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
  
#memberOneForm, #memberTwoForm, #memberThreeForm, #memberFourForm, #memberFiveForm, #memberSixForm {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
}
  
.stats {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 30px 16px 20px 15px;
  gap: 3px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
  
.line-one, .line-two, .line-three, .line-four {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
}
  
.line-one {
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
  
.line-three  {
  justify-content: end;
}
  
.name {
  min-width: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
  
p {
  margin: 0;
}

.level-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: end;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

#level-text {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.level-number {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.types {
  width: 75%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
}

#type-one, #type-two {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.status {
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.hp-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #555555;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-right: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hp-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: width 0.2s linear;
}
<div class='popup'></div>




Please post a [mcve]. You can use a Stack Snippet to make it executable.

You might find reading the site help section useful when it comes to asking a good question. To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a minimal reproducible example. Here's a question checklist you might find useful...

@Barmar I added a codepen link. I'm having trouble getting the "Update" button to work and store the new currentHp value. It is reverting to "90" on each click. If that can be solved, then it should behave similarly to how the extension does, in parsing information. The party array must be in the function as that is how it is interpreted in the extension.

You reinitialize the party and members arrays every time you click on the button. They should probably be global variables that you initialize just once.

@Barmar that makes sense, but this is all wrapped in "chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener()" because I'm receiving the game information and that creates the values for the variables. If I put them outside the chrome.runtime function, then the values are not attributed.

They shouldn't be outside that, they just need to be outside subtractHp()

your code was hard to dissect..
The sequences of value assignments are strange,
and you placed the function setHp() inside the loop members.forEach( member => !
Here is what I understand about it, as well as a simpler(?) way to do this....


const 
  hpBarGreen  = '#39ff7b'
, hpBarYellow = '#f3b200'
, hpBarRed    = '#fb3041'
, cardColor   = '#ffffcc'  // ?
, party       = [{ currentHP: 90,  maxHP: 100 }]
, members     = [{ cardId: 'cardOne', currentHp: party[0].currentHP, maxHp: party[0].maxHP }]
, popup       = document.querySelector('.popup');
  ;

function subtractHp()
  {
  popup.innerHTML = '';
  members.forEach( member =>
    {
    let 
      hpPercentage = (member.currentHp / member.maxHp) * 100
    , fragHTML     = new Range().createContextualFragment(`
        <div class="pokemon-card" id="${member.cardId}">
          <div class="stats">
            <div class="line-one"></div>
            <div class="line-two"></div>
            <div class="line-three"></div>
            <div class="line-four">
              <div class="hp-container">
                <div class="hp-bar" id="${member.cardId}Hp" style=""></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>`);

    setHp( fragHTML.querySelector(`#${member.cardId}Hp`), hpPercentage );
    
    popup.append(fragHTML);
    member.currentHp -= 40;
    });

  function setHp( hp_x, percentage )    // OUTSIDE THE LOOP members.forEach( member => 
    {
    hp_x.style.width           = percentage + '%';
    hp_x.style.backgroundColor = (percentage <= 25) ? hpBarRed
                               : (percentage <= 50) ? hpBarYellow
                               : hpBarGreen;
    }
  }
@font-face {
  font-family : False-Positive;
  src         : url(./fonts/falsepos.ttf);
  }
body {
  margin      : 0;
  padding     : 0;
  border      : 0;
  font-family : False-Positive;
  color       : #333333;
  }
.hide {
  display : none;
  }
.popup {
  width              : 500px;
  height             : 800px;
  background-color   : #e5e4c5ff;
  display            : grid;
  grid-template-rows : repeat(6, 1fr);
  align-items        : center;
  justify-content    : center;
  }
.pokemon-card {
  position         : relative;
  width            : 300px;
  height           : 100px;
  background-color : #777777;
  display          : flex;
  overflow         : hidden;
  align-items      : center;
  border           : #777777 solid 2px;
  }
.sprite {
  min-width             : 100px;
  width                 : 100px;
  height                : 100px;
  display               : grid;
  grid-template-columns : repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows    : repeat(3, 1fr);
  position              : relative;
  align-items           : center;
  justify-content       : center;
  }
.pokemon-sprite {
  grid-column : 1 / span 3;
  grid-row    : 1 / span 3;
  max-width   : 85%;
  margin-left : 5px;
  }
#memberOneForm,
#memberTwoForm,
#memberThreeForm,
#memberFourForm,
#memberFiveForm,
#memberSixForm {
  grid-column : 1;
  grid-row    : 1;
  z-index     : 1;
  width       : 100%;
  }
.stats {
  max-width          : 100%;
  height             : 100%;
  display            : grid;
  grid-template-rows : 30px 16px 20px 15px;
  gap                : 3px;
  padding-top        : 5px;
  }
.line-one,
.line-two,
.line-three,
.line-four {
  display : flex;
  width   : 200px;
  }
.line-one {
  justify-content : space-between;
  align-items     : center;
  }
.line-three {
  justify-content : end;
  }
.name {
  min-width : 0;
  font-size : 30px;
  }
p {
  margin : 0;
  }
.level-container {
  display        : flex;
  flex-direction : column;
  align-items    : end;
  padding-right  : 5px;
  }
#level-text {
  font-size : 10px;
  }
.level-number {
  font-size : 18px;
  }
.types {
  width   : 75%;
  height  : 100%;
  display : flex;
  gap     : 5px;
  }
#type-one,
#type-two {
  max-height : 100%;
  max-width  : 100%;
  }
.status {
  border-radius : 20px;
  margin-right  : 3px;
  margin-top    : 2px;
  }
.hp-container {
  width            : 100%;
  height           : 100%;
  background-color : #555555;
  border-radius    : 10px;
  border           : 2px solid black;
  margin-right     : 3px;
  overflow         : hidden;
  }
.hp-bar {
  width  : 100%;
  height : 100%;
  }
<div class="popup"></div>
<button onClick="subtractHp()">Update</button>




Thank you for the help! I updated the original post to show the exact code I'm working on, hopefully to offer some clarification. It seems to be initializing the values on each update and I'm unsure on where to place setHp() to actually have the transition active.

@PsychedelicSeal  You're kidding me! -> I've already spent 2 hours to understand your code, and now you're changing all the information about your problem!

As @Bremer said, the problem is that you initialize the arrays inside the function and then every time you call the function - they return to their initial values.
The solution is to take the arrays out of the function so that they are global variables


const hpBarGreen = "#39ff7b";
const hpBarYellow = "#f3b200";
const hpBarRed = "#fb3041";
const cardColor = "#ffffcc";
   const party = [{
    currentHP: 90,
    maxHP: 100
  }];
  const members = [{
    cardId: "cardOne",
    currentHp: party[0].currentHP,
    maxHp: party[0].maxHP
  }];
function subtractHp() {
   

  const popup = document.querySelector(".popup");
  popup.innerHTML = "";

  members.forEach((member) => {
    const card = document.createElement("div");
    card.className = "pokemon-card";
    card.id = member.cardId;

    const stats = document.createElement("div");
    stats.className = "stats";

    const lineOne = document.createElement("div");
    lineOne.className = "line-one";

    const lineTwo = document.createElement("div");
    lineTwo.className = "line-two";

    const lineThree = document.createElement("div");
    lineThree.className = "line-three";

    const lineFour = document.createElement("div");
    lineFour.className = "line-four";

    const hpContainer = document.createElement("div");
    hpContainer.className = "hp-container";

    const hp = document.createElement("div");
    hp.className = "hp-bar";
    hp.id = member.cardId + "Hp";

    member.currentHp -= 40;

    const hpPercentage = (member.currentHp / member.maxHp) * 100;

    function setHp(percentage) {
      hp.style.width = percentage + "%";
      if (percentage <= 25) {
        hp.style.backgroundColor = hpBarRed;
      } else if (percentage <= 50) {
        hp.style.backgroundColor = hpBarYellow;
      } else {
        hp.style.backgroundColor = hpBarGreen;
      }
    }

    popup.appendChild(card);
    card.appendChild(stats);
    stats.appendChild(lineOne);
    stats.appendChild(lineTwo);
    stats.appendChild(lineThree);
    stats.appendChild(lineFour);
    lineFour.appendChild(hpContainer);
    hpContainer.appendChild(hp);

    setHp(hpPercentage);
  });
}
@font-face {
  font-family: False-Positive;
  src: url(./fonts/falsepos.ttf);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-family: False-Positive;
  color: #333333;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.popup {
  width: 500px;
  height: 800px;
  background-color: #e5e4c5ff;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.pokemon-card {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #777777;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-items: center;
  border: #777777 solid 2px;
}

.sprite {
  min-width: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.pokemon-sprite {
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  grid-row: 1 / span 3;
  max-width: 85%;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#memberOneForm,
#memberTwoForm,
#memberThreeForm,
#memberFourForm,
#memberFiveForm,
#memberSixForm {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
}

.stats {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 30px 16px 20px 15px;
  gap: 3px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.line-one,
.line-two,
.line-three,
.line-four {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
}

.line-one {
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.line-three {
  justify-content: end;
}

.name {
  min-width: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

.level-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: end;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

#level-text {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.level-number {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.types {
  width: 75%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
}

#type-one,
#type-two {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.status {
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.hp-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #555555;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-right: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hp-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
<div class="popup"></div>
<button onClick="subtractHp()">Update</button>




The only problem is that this is all wrapped in "chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener()" because I'm receiving the game information and that creates the values for the variables. If I put them outside the chrome.runtime function, then the values are not attributed.

My intention was not to have you take the variables out of chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener. The variables can stay up to date inside the listener,
My intention was to take the variables out of the subtractHp function, so that they wouldn't be reset every time you call that function. That way, it would only be initialized in the listener. And when the function is called, it wouldn't be initialized every time.

Thank you for your patience and sorry I'm not being very clear. I'm still a relatively novice programmer and this is one of my first non-guided projects. I updated the original post with a Snippet that includes exactly what the code I'm working on is. I made some optimizations, so it's different from the original, but hopefully gives a much better indicator of what is going on.
